# jQuery in UpdatePanel in ASP.NET error

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I have a JQuery script in a asp:Panel in an UpdatePanel which is in  an ASP.NET page. This is the code.

```
 <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Panel runat="server" ID="ImagePanel">
            <img id="photo" src="/Icons/Factory Layout.png" style="display:none"/>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                $(document).ready(function () {
                    var factoryImage = $("#photo");                 
                    factoryImage.attr("src",document.getElementById('<%= FactoryImageFileNameHF.ClientID %>').value);
                    factoryImage.show();
                    $('#photo').imgAreaSelect({
                        handles: true,
                        show: true,
                        onSelectEnd: function(img, selection) {
                            var X1 = document.getElementById('<%= X1HF.ClientID %>');
                            var Y1 = document.getElementById('<%= Y1HF.ClientID %>');
                            var X2 = document.getElementById('<%= X2HF.ClientID %>');
                            var Y2 = document.getElementById('<%= Y2HF.ClientID %>');
                            X1.value = selection.x1;
                            X2.value = selection.x2;
                            Y1.value = selection.y1;
                            Y2.value = selection.y2;                              
                        }                           
                    });
                });
            </script>
        </asp:Panel>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

I have the following link in the head of the web form.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.imgareaselect.pack.js"></script>
```

I have the following errors

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
at eval (eval at <anonymous> (jquery.imgareaselect.pack.js:1), <anonymous>:1:10852)
at jquery.imgareaselect.pack.js:1
FactoryLayoutSettings.aspx:543 Uncaught TypeError: $ is not a function    
at FactoryLayoutSettings.aspx:555    
(anonymous) @ FactoryLayoutSettings.aspx:555
```

As I am new to jQuery I am not really sure of where the error is. Is it a result of the UpdatePanel because at the beginning the image shows and then on a postback it fails and I get the errors above? The underlined part of the code where it fails is $(document).ready(function (). Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: You need to import jquery before importing jquery.imgareaselect.pack.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before the `script` tag you have mentioned you should also have another one `script` tag, in which you would refer to jQuery. As it seems you make use of jQuery but you haven't loaded the library, before you use it.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="..."></script>
```

In the `src` `...` should be replaced with the path to the jQuery.

Comment: I actually have <script async src="/Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script> in the master page. What loads first the page or master?

Comment: @EmptyWaterHoles The master page would contain a section, in which you append the content of each page you create. If I remember it correct, it should be called `<asp:Content..`. So if you have this tag at the head of you master page normally you shouldn't experience any such an issue. That I suspect here is that you have this script tag after the closing tag of `</asp:Content>`. If so, you load the jQuery later than it is needed.

Comment: jquery.min.js is the jQuery that worked. For some strange reason jquery-3.0.0.min.js did not work. The 3rd party plugin did suggest jquery.min.js. I am going to select your answer as correct because you were first. Thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: @EmptyWaterHoles Actually in production you should use the minified versions of the libraries you use, in order to save bandwidth. However, I still think that the issue was where you had the script tag related with the jQuery. Did you change this or only the reference from the jQuery to the jQuery minified? Last but no least provided that jQuery script is valid the only difference with the jQuery. minified is that the latter is minified (because it doesn't contains spaces, new line characters, etc...). Essentially there isn't any other difference.

Comment: Yes actually, where the JQuery's were declared was important. jQuery-3.0.0.min.js was declared in the html of the master page. jQuery.min.js was in the head content-placeholder and was being overridden. I moved jQuery.min.js to the content-placeholder which was in the body of the master page(but on the web-form) and it worked. Thanks for your help. But the strange thing about it was it was working sometimes before but not always. Now it works perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

The code you are using requires JQuery.

Add another script resource to your page:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to include JQuery before you actually use it.

First, create a required bundle for your jquery scripts you want on every page:

```
public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
    bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/js/required").Include(
        "~/Scripts/jquery-2.0.2.js"));

    //other bundles
}
```

Now include this bundle into your page-

```
<body>
    @RenderBody()
    @Scripts.Render("~/js/required") //Here add your jquery include
    @RenderSection("scripts", false) //Here you add scripts at the bottom of the page
</body>
```

It should solve your issue.